# When to use QString{...}, tr(...) and +=/append?

Tags: qt, string-concatenation, qstring

The information about what `QString` can do is wide spread in the extensive Qt documentation. But from information overflow I am not sure when I should use what tool best.

For a simple report generator from a form I now have this code, mainly relying on `tr` and `arg` to create the `QString` for the final `QMessageBox`:

```
void Dialog::analyseDialog() {
    QString str{};
    if( ui.lineEdit->text().isEmpty()) {
        str += tr("Name: keine Angaben\n");
    } else {
        str += tr("Name: %1\n").arg(ui.lineEdit->text());
    }
    if( ui.spinBox->cleanText().isEmpty()) {
        str += tr("Geburtsdatum: keine Angaben\n");
    } else {
        str += tr("Geburtsdatum: %1\n").arg(ui.spinBox->cleanText());
    }
    if( ui.radioButton->isChecked()) {
        str += tr("Geschlecht: weiblich\n");
    } else {
        str += tr("Geschlecht: männlich\n");
    }
    QMessageBox::information(0, tr("Die Auswertung"), str);
}
```

But I am not sure if this is correctly used:

- Is using `tr()` appropriate if I don't expect localization?
- or should I use `QString{...}`-c'tor instead?
- Is `+=` (or `.append`) efficient with Qt? It is supposed to use `QStringBuffer` internally. Sometimes... err... what?
- Or is there a much better approach?

Comment: 1) I would use `tr` for every translatable string (even when you are not going to translate it right now). This is true for almost every string which is displayed to the user, but not for technical string such as query strings. 2) I wouldn't care that much about efficiency, as every approach is almost always more than fast enough. Qt allocates extra space to avoid frequent reallocations. Conclusion: your approach seems right to me.

Comment: A couple of links to make the picture more complete: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/13/string-concatenation-with-qstringbuilder/ https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html

Answer (score 0):

Q:Is += (or .append) efficient with Qt? It is supposed to use QStringBuffer internally. Sometimes... err... what?

A: You may have java experience, in java, a String is not modifiable, you concatenate it by making a new String, That's why java recommends using StringBuffer, in C++, std::string or QString is a vector-like object,
something like StringBuffer in java, so += or append is efficient